# Error gbak Restore firebird 1.5 on Firebird 2.5 Mac os

Tags: firebird, osx-yosemite, firebird2.5, firebird1.5

I want to restore my firebird 1.5 database backuped on Windows with gbak on a 2.5 Firebird database on Mac OS 10.10 with the following command

```
gbak -rep -r o -v -fix_fss_metadata ISO-8859-1 -fix_fss_data ISO-8859-1 -user SYSDBA -password masterkey /Users/admin/Downloads/THERIA/THERIA.fbk localhost:/SourceMediintel/BD/BDD/Theria.fdb
```

but I've the following error

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
```

Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Versions/A/Resources/bin/gbak
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Versions/A/Resources/bin/gbak
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

After searching, I foud that I must update Mac OS beacuse this is was fixed from 10.12. Is this's the only way or there's another method to proceed ?

Many thank in advance for your help.

Comment: Not related to the question, but are you sure you should be using `-fix_fss_metadata ISO-8859-1 -fix_fss_data ISO-8859-1` that is a great way to corrupt the metadata and data in your database if you didn't actually have the problem those options intend to fix.

Comment: In any case, you could try if using the service manager to restore solves this, but as it uses the same underlying code, that is not very likely; I'd also guess the same function might be used in other Firebird internals, so Firebird itself might not even work. I suggest you ask this on the firebird-support mailinglist though, likely the maintainer of the Mac build can give you a solution, or a final verdict if you'd need to upgrade or not.

Comment: well, I've added encoding to prevent data import errors. But the problem seems to be from Mac OS version ... I'm not sure

Comment: Using those options when they aren't needed can corrupt data by applying an incorrect character set transliteration. You shouldn't apply it unless you are absolutely certain you need it (and by the sound of it, you're just guessing).

Comment: After multiple searches, it seems that I must update Mac OS to 10.13 version to fix this problem

Comment: The maintainer of the MacOS build is considering releasing a new build that doesn't need this function.

Comment: I forgot to post a follow-up, but a new build of Firebird 2.5.8 (2.5.8-27089-1) for the Mac was released which fixes this problem. Available on : https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/#MacOSX